# vim: hide first n letters of all lines in a file

Tags: vim

I am analyzing log file using vim and the format looks like this

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.USEC PID Name LogText`

Since Most of the times I don't care about date and time. I want to hide them and just focus on the Name and LogText columns (To save some screen estate). Since the first three columns always occupy the first 35 letters in a line. Is there a way to make vim not display first 35 letters of each line ?

Comment: I don't know how you do it in vim, but if you don't mind creating a temporary file, you could run `cut -c36- logfile > logfile_with_first_35_chars_missing`, and then review that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You asked about how to hide the first letters, not to remove them, or scroll them out of sight - so here is how to actually hide them:

### Hide text in vim using conceal

You can use **matching**, combined with **syntax highlighting** and the **conceal** feature to actually not show matched characters inside lines.

To hide the first 25 chars of each line:

```
:syn match Concealed '^.\{25\}' conceal
:set conceallevel=2
```

To hide only the lines with the punctuation of a date instead:

```
:syn match Concealed '^....-..-.. ..:..:..\..... ' conceal
```

To unhide:

```
:syn clear Concealed
:set conceallevel=0
```

What looks like this normally:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.USEC PID Name LogText
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.USEC PID Name LogText
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.USEC PID Name LogText
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.USEC PID Name LogText
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.USEC PID Name LogText
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.USEC PID Name LogText
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.USEC PID Name LogText
```

will look like this after executing the first two commands:

```
PID Name LogText
PID Name LogText
PID Name LogText
PID Name LogText
PID Name LogText
PID Name LogText
PID Name LogText
```

---

See also - inside `vim`:
`help :syn-match`
`help :syn-conceal`
`help 'conceallevel'`
`help 'concealcursor'`

---

(Let me know if it does not behave like that - there may be some more setting I'm not aware of or so - I'll get it to work.)

Comment: Works fine, I think vim needs to be compiled with `+conceal` (mine is) option for this to work. Also good to do `set concealcursor=nc` to prevent the cursor line from expanding.

Comment: Yes, the `+conceal` feature option is standard like some years. Sad that it's not more well-known by now. It's really great and flexible. Gives **lots** of new options...

Answer (score 10):

Use vim's [filter functionality](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#filter). Run:

```
:%!cut -b36-
```

to run the contents of your buffer through the [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) command, retaining only bytes 36 and onwards. `%` means to run the entire buffer through and replace its contents with the output, then `!` is the filter command, with the rest of the line as the program to run. This doesn't modify the underlying file unless you then save the buffer over the top.

To get the original untrimmed buffer back you can use `:e`, provided that it's backed by a real file.

Comment: And then use `%!cat %` to get it back ? This works great and I can use a `map` to toggle between these two

Comment: Yes, that will work, as long as you have a real file backing your buffer.

Comment: @Michael Homer: This will now work with unicode characters.

Answer (score 6):

I think more in line with what you're looking for is **horizontal scrolling**.

`Z` is the horizontal scrolling command key, followed by a direction to move with the left or right arrow key.

First `:set nowrap` to disable line wrapping. Then press <kbd>z</kbd>,<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>,<kbd>→</kbd> to scroll 35 spaces.

Comment: This is very useful when reading logs, thank you!

Comment: ok, great for a single page, but... How to do page down or page up without the cursor jumping again to the beginning of the line?

Comment: just found how to do it in the @user2987828 answer: using `:set nosol`

Comment: Place cursor on the last character you want hidden. Then type... `[Esc]` `z` `s`

Answer (score 2):

In command mode, try:

```
:%s/^.\{35}//
```

- `%s/pat/sub/`: replace each occurence of *pat* with *sub*
- `^.\{35}`: match first 35 characters of line

This command remove first 35 characters of each line. You can read `:h regular-expression` for more details about regular expression in `vim`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy to remember solution, without modifying buffers or files. Place your cursor on the first character (`L` on your example) of the file portion you want to see, then type

```
:set nowrap
zs
```

The `zs` command will setup vi so that that the character with the cursor appears at first column of the screen. Be sure that you didn't type `:set nosol` in your configuration files.

The `g$` command will move your cursor to the last visible column.

The `g0` command will move back your cursor to the first visible column, the one containing L.

If any key moves the cursor to left or right out of the visible columns, then the visible windows will shift.

Comment: And `g0` command will move your cursor to the first visible column